# Is there a way to retrieve all events where a admin of an Github repo bypassed a branch protection rule, of any rule at all?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'm currently working on auditing the administrative activities within a specific GitHub repository, particularly any instances where branch protection rules might have been bypassed.

Is there a mechanism, either through the GitHub API or the GitHub web interface, where I can retrieve all events or logs indicating that an administrator bypassed a branch protection rule?
Can I specifically retrieve events regardless of which particular rule was bypassed, meaning I want a comprehensive list of all rule bypasses without needing to specify which rule?